# I am not able to use RestApi in android application

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

Here is my RestApi get call result 
[RestApi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OAUg.png)

An in my android application i am using the retrofit library to call this api to show items in my android application, here is the api call in android

```
package com.aditmsolutions.www.foodie;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL = "https://10.0.2.2:51087/api/";
    @GET("items")
    Call<List<Item>> getItems();
}
```

When I run my app it gives this error message "HandShake failed"
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZYN7.png)
Please help

And here is [logcat view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ1SD.png)

And her is the code to getItems

```
private void getItems() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are      using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
            .build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    Call<List<Item>> call = api.getItems();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Item>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Item>> call, Response<List<Item>>   response) {
            List<Item> itemList = response.body();

            //Creating an String array for the ListView
            String[] items = new String[itemList.size()];

            //looping through all the heroes and inserting the names inside the string array
            for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
                items[i] = itemList.get(i).getTitle();
            }


            //displaying the string array into listview
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Item>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post your full error with stacktrace

Comment: Also Post Item class and json response And Logcat error

Comment: Json response is attached as picture

Comment: share the code where you are calling `getItems()` and also the retrofit call

Comment: probably not related to retrofit. Does the base URL accept HTTPS connections? try with http first and see if it works

Comment: @OmarAlHalabi thankyou the handshake error has gone when i enabled https connecction but now it give this exception java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found